# CentOS live CD does not boot 

Tags: centos, live-cd

Seems very trivial but still ...
I followed the instructions here:

https://projects.centos.org/trac/livecd/wiki/CreateImage

None of the images created boot. I tried VMWARE Workstation (v6.5) as well as VirtualBox v3.2OSE.

In both cases I see the grub screen, and upon loading the kernel, the VM Guest freezes and nothing happens.

I used CentOS 5.5 to create the images, can someone confirm this behavior ? Or at least tell me how to debug it ?

Thanks in advance,

Oz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would try one of the ready-made LiveCDs, [available for download here](http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOSLiveCD5.5). If those do not work, you know you have some problem in your environment. If those do you know there is some issue with the livecd-create script. There is more explanation as to how the creation process works [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedoraLiveCD/LiveCDHowTo),  so I would step through this bit by bit to see where corruption is occuring.

Another tip is that you need to be careful in certain situations, for example if you are creating an image on a 64-bit system but your VM is 32-bit.